# Panda's chunksize equivalent in feather file?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, feather

I am trying to convert my code which used csv/txt file to feather file code. I read the file like `df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Saad.Saleem\Downloads\message.txt", engine='python', sep=';', encoding='utf-8', chunksize=10)` but I can't find chunksize equivalent in feather.